# Add some specific time while using the linux command "date"

Tags: linux, date

In linux, `date` can help me to print the current time. If want to print the current time + 1 hour, what option should I give?

Comment: If you are trying to do timezone corrections, do look at the `TZ` environment variables and store dates in UTC!

Comment: I just want to get the current time and 1 hour later as the inputs of my another code, thank you.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

### On Linux

Just use `-d` (or `--date`) to do some math with the dates:

```sh
date -d '+1 hour' '+%F %T'
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For example:

```sh
$ date '+%F %T'
2013-04-22 10:57:24
$ date -d '+1 hour' '+%F %T'
2013-04-22 11:57:24
#           ^
```

### On Mac OS

Warning, the above only works on Linux, not on Mac OS.

On Mac OS, the equivalent command is

```
date -v+1H
```

Comment: We can also add time to a given date, like this:

     $ date -d "May 16 10:41:56 EDT 2017 + 12360.471 seconds"
     Tue May 16 14:07:56 EDT 2017

Comment: Somebody please add that to `man date(1)` page!

Comment: I'd like to know exactly how it works. From my example I see is does NOT calculate from left to right: `date +'%F %T' -d'2023-09-19 -30 days 1 month'` results in `2023-09-19`, not `2023-09-20` (8th month has 31 days).

Comment: @Martian2020 I recall `date -d` has some weird behaviour with the first parameter, since it tends to consider it the year --> [date processes first parameter incorrectly if it is not 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211796/40596)

Answer (score 12):

In shell script, if we need to add time then use below command and date format(PUT TIME before DATE string)

`date -d"11:15:10 2017-02-05 +2 hours" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
this will output
`2017-02-05 13:15:10`

THis does not result in correct date without UTC it does not work

Comment: Alternatively to putting time first one may omit `+`, just  `date -d" 2017-02-05 11:15:10 2 hours"` (as suggested in another answer).

Answer (score 6):

## Linux and macOS in a single command

If you need to write scripts that work on both Linux servers and macOS workstations, you can silence the error of the first `date` call and 'OR' it (`||`) with the other. It doesn't matter which comes first.

```sh
date -u -d "+${max_age}Seconds" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" 2>/dev/null || \
date -u -v "+${max_age}S"       +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
```

For example, this bash function uploads a file to AWS S3 and sets a `Expires:` and `Cache-Control:` headers.

```sh
s3_upload_cache_control(){
  local max_age_seconds="${1}" ;shift         # required
  local bucket_path="${1}"     ;shift         # required
  local filename="${1}"        ;shift         # required
  local remote_filename="/${1:-${filename}}"  # optional
  local fmt="+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
  aws s3 cp                                                          \
    "${filename}"                                                    \
    "s3://${bucket_path}${remote_filename}"                          \
    --expires                                                  "$(   \
      date -u -d "+${max_age_seconds}Seconds" $fmt 2>/dev/null  ||   \
      date -u -v "+${max_age_seconds}S"       $fmt               )"  \
    --cache-control max-age=$max_age,public                          \
    --acl public-read
}
```

Answer (score 6):

for me adding the plus `+` just made it think i want to use timezone.

so

```
date -d "2021-03-16 00:00:00 +3 minutes" +'%H:%M'
```

returned `23:01` which is weird..

but i omit the plus sign, and just do this:

```
date -d "2021-03-16 00:00:00 1 hour" +'%H:%M'
```

and that returns `01:00`.

Comment: The answer from 2018 warns: "(PUT TIME before DATE string)".  There is also warning about UTC there., effect of which I did not understand. Omitting `+` works too. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According this [source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-get-yesterdays-tomorrows-date.html) you can just do:

> date --date='1 hour'

Answer (score 1):

in linux just use `date -d '+1 hour'` from the command line

Answer (score 0):

`TZ=Asia/Calcutta date` should work (obviously this will get you the time in Calcutta).

This changes your TimeZone (`TZ`) environment variable for this operation only, it won't permanently set you to the new time zone you specify.

Comment: Cough! While I was going to ask about timezones, hardcoding it to match **your** incidental local timezone is ... very likely not going to be what the OP needs to do.

Comment: This doesn't change anything on a permanent basis @sehe, it just changes the variable for the scope of a single operation. If he wants `Europe/London` or `America/Chicago` he can just substitute those in.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is just wrong. It may seem to work most of the time, but at some point it **will** fail. For example when the destination TZ has switched to summer time but yours hasn't.

Comment: @Oshawott I know right, it's about not explaining what magic to use to get to the timezones. See my [comment at the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142973/add-some-specific-time-while-using-the-linux-command-date/16143047?noredirect=1#comment23062965_16142973), really

Answer (score 0):

We can get it using below code, i was handling a case wherein i required to traverse dates from last 3 months, i used below code to traverse the same

## !/bin/sh

```
for i in {90..1}
  do
   st_dt=$(date +%F' 00:00:00'  -d "-$i days")
   echo $st_dt
   j=$((i-1))
   end_dt=$(date +%F' 00:00:00'  -d "-$j days")
   echo $end_dt
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux shell script to add 1 hour or 60 minutes.

```
dt=$(date -d '+ 60 minutes'  '+%FT%T.000Z')
```