# Construct a new date by adding X number of hours (Unix Shell)

Tags: shell, date, unix

Given a UNIX date variable, I need to construct a new date adding a certain number of hours (must be variable) to the initial date. I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142973/add-some-specific-time-while-using-the-linux-command-date), which explains how to do this with the current date. For example with 1 hour, `date -d '+1 hour' '+%F %T'` returns the time it will be in exactly one hour. However, I need to do this with a date variable, not with the current date.

I've tried messing around with the `-d` flag, but if I set the date to another date variable, I can't figure out how to change it again (such as adding another X number of hours).

Is there a good way to do this? Am I on the right track with the `-d` flag or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# your date variable
dt=$(date -d '2016-08-15 11:10:15')

# add 1 hour to $dt now
date -d "$dt +1 hour"
Mon Aug 15 12:10:15 EDT 2016
```