# Addition to a Date in bash script

Tags: bash, time, date-arithmetic, arithmetic-expressions

I wanted to add 1 hour to a date time. So I tried this -

```
date -u -d "2019-02-22 05:21:22 + 1 hour" +"%F %T"
```

And I got this as output -

> 2019-02-22 05:21:22

There was no addition to hours. So I played a bit more with date -

```
    date -u -d "2019-02-22 05:21:22 + 12 hours" +"%F %T"
    > 2019-02-21 18:21:22

    date -u -d "2019-02-22 05:21:22 - 12 hours" +"%F %T"
    > 2019-02-22 18:21:22

    date -u -d "2019-02-22 05:21:22 + 1 minutes" +"%F %T"
    > 2019-02-22 04:22:22

    date -u -d "2019-02-22 05:21:22 + 1 day" +"%F %T"
    > 2019-02-23 04:21:22
```

The output for each command is so confusing. I am unable to figure out how to add hours or any other time to date.

I searched online of how to use date command and went through posts like -

- [add-some-specific-time-while-using-the-linux-command-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142973/add-some-specific-time-while-using-the-linux-command-date)
- [how-to-add-n-hours-to-a-specified-time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564976/how-to-add-n-hours-to-a-specified-time)
- [linux-add-x-days-to-date-and-get-new-virtual-date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49053/linux-add-x-days-to-date-and-get-new-virtual-date)
- [calculating-time-adding-minutes-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208473/calculating-time-adding-minutes-bash)

Most of them from above and others that I wnent thorugh have the same format to add to dates as I tried to use but it didn't work out for me.

So I would like some help in understanding how to add hours/minutes/days or any other unit of time to date and what is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you use option `-u`?

Comment: For considering time to be in utc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parsing date time arithmetic is hard. Given:

```
date -u -d "2019-02-22 05:21:22 + 1 hour" +"%F %T"
```

date takes this part `05:21:22 + 1 hour` to mean `05:21:22+0100 hour` which it *then* interprets as `05:21:22+0100 +1 hour`. Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html

You can help resolve the ambiguity by putting the relative time in a different spot:

```
# ............vvvvvvvv
$ date -u -d "+ 1 hour 2019-02-22 05:21:22" +"%F %T"
2019-02-22 06:21:22
# .........^^
# .......................vvvvvvvv
$ date -u -d "2019-02-22 + 1 hour 05:21:22" +"%F %T"
2019-02-22 06:21:22
# .........^^
# ................................vvvvvvvv
$ date -u -d "2019-02-22 05:21:22 + 1 hour" +"%F %T"
2019-02-22 05:21:22
# .........^^
```

Or, specify a timezone yourself

```
# ...............................v
$ date -u -d "2019-02-22 05:21:22Z + 1 hour" +"%F %T"
2019-02-22 06:21:22
# .........^^
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn for explanation.